# IntersectionObserver Multiple Entries

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can anyone explain to me why an observer set up to observe a single element would return multiple IntersectionObserverEntry's? I've noticed this in my Vue project, but it isn't consistent and it seems to only occur in recent versions of Chrome.

I wish I could provide a fiddle replicating the issue, but I can't seem to replicate it must be something related to my project. Just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction as to why this could be happening.

Here's my jsfiddle (even though it doesn't display this behaviour)

```
<div id="app"> 
  <img :alt="x" v-for="x in 20" v-lazy="'https://picsum.photos/400/600/?random'"/>
</div>

function isObject (value) {
  return value && typeof value === 'object' && value.constructor === Object;
}

function init (el, binding) {
  let options = {
    threshold: 0.10
  }    

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    console.log(el, entries)
    if (entries[0].isIntersecting || entries[0].intersectionRatio > 0) {
      // console.log('is intersecting', el)
      // Create a new Image object
      let img = new Image();

      // Incase we want to add a css effect
      el.classList.add('js-lazy', 'js-lazy--loading');

      // Setup an onload event for the image
      img.onload = () => {
        if (el.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
          // Use img src
          el.setAttribute('src', img.src);
        } else {
          // Use background image style
          el.style.backgroundImage = `url('${ img.src }')`;
        }

        // Add a loaded class which we can use to remove the css effect
        el.classList.remove('js-lazy--loading');
      }

      // Set the image src to trigger the image to load
      if (isObject(binding.value)) {
        img.src = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches ? binding.value.mobile : binding.value.desktop;
      } else {
        img.src = binding.value;
      }

      // Remove the observer as the element is now within view
      observer.unobserve(el);
      observer = null;
    }
  }, options);

  // Start the observer
  observer.observe(el);
}

Vue.directive('lazy', {
  bind: function (el, binding) {
    // If binding has a value when the directive binds to the element
    // then we can run init()
    if (binding.value.length > 0 || isObject(binding.value)) {
      // console.log('init on bind', el);
      init(el, binding);
    }
  },

  update: function (el, binding) {
    // If binding didn't have a value when the directive was initially bound to the element
    // then run init() when the old and current values do not match
    if (typeof binding.value === 'object') {
      if (binding.value.desktop === binding.oldValue.desktop) { 
        return;
      }
    } else if (binding.value === binding.oldValue) {
      return;
    }

    // console.log('init on update', el);
    init(el, binding);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

Comment: Did you find out what was happening? I'm trying to understand what could cause multiple entries (even if I've never faced this scenario).